# Flipping Around 5 percent of 1's and 0's

Tags: matlab, matrix

For the following letter, I wish to add noise to it by changing 5 percent of the 1's into 0's. So far, I have the following code which turns them all into 0's. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you!

```
letterA = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
           0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
           0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
           0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]; 

for i=1:numel(letterA)
    if letterA(i)==1
        letterA(i)=0;
    end
end

disp(letterA)
```

Comment: I don't know that language, so I can't provide a code example. But you could have a variable of the integer type, and add +1 to it on each iteration. Whenever it can be divided by 20, flip the bit. Or better than that, to make things random (otherwise I wouldn't think of it as noise) - on each iteration, generate a random number between 1 and 20. If you get a 20, flip the bit. P.S. I got some degree of sinestesia... That A appears to my eyes as a big, pink, 3D letter comming out of the monitor. Thanks for the art :)

Comment: If you want 5% of all the nonzero bits flipped *on average*, you can use Andreas or Ran's solution. If you want *exactly* 5% of nonzero bits flipped, use Eitan's solution. In any case: in most situations, *real* noise does not only destroy signals, it also *creates* signals, meaning, some of those zeros should turn into 1s as well. Also, the way you have it defined now means that `letterA` is of type `double`, which wastes 64 times more space than necessary :) What would be wrong with `logical(letterA)`? It's easier to use things like `letterA(letterA)` to index the non-zero bits that way...

Comment: @EitanT not sure why you think that; flipping x values with uniform probability of 5% means that elements in any subset y *also* have 5% chance of being flipped...0.05*N == (0.05*N/m)*m

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Yes, had a mind block there. This still may produce unacceptable results in individual trials, such as 3% and 7%. Is that what the OP wants?

Comment: @EitanT it would appear so, as he stated "around 5%" :) But it all depends on what the OP thinks the term "around" means :P

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis "Around 5%" in the title, "5% of the ones" in the question itself :)

Comment: @EitanT: OP! please help us solve this conundrum!

Comment: @EitanT: I thought it over, and came up with something different please let me know what you think.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Please see comment above.

Comment: @Andreas H.: Please see comment above.

Comment: @ShankarKumar Whatever your solution is, you should define the problem first. Once you determine the properties of the noise you want to add, a proper answer can be given to your question.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
letterA( letterA == 1 & rand(size(letterA)) <= 0.05 ) = 0;
```

In fact you could also do

```
letterA( rand(size(letterA)) <= 0.05 ) = 0;
```

which sets each element with probability of 5% to zero. The already zero elements are not affected. I think what causes confusion here is that you have to recognize that each element is independently handled from each other. It makes no difference if you do the first or the second version.

You can check it:

```
 letterA = (rand(1e5,1) < 0.2); N1 = nnz(letterA);
 letterA( rand(size(letterA)) <= 0.05 ) = 0;
 (N1 - nnz(letterA))/N1
```

which gives values around 0.05, i.e. 5%. And it is not true what EitanT says, that it will flip at maximum 5%. It can be more than 5% or less, but on average it is 5%.

EitanTs version flippes exactly 5%, so which version to select depends on the application. For EitanT version the noise is correlated to the signal (because it is exact), which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to operate on 5% of the "1"s (it'll work only if the "1"s overlap with the values of the random matrix that are less than 0.05...)

Comment: @EitanT: You are incorrect. Check out the following:
letterA = (rand(1e5,1) < 0.2);
N1 = nnz(letterA);
letterA( letterA == 1 & rand(size(letterA)) < 0.05 ) = 0;
(N1 - nnz(letterA))/N1
This gives removes exactly 5% of 1s. Hence my solution is exactly what the OP wants. I believe yours is incorrect.

Comment: Suppose that `rand` produces a random matrix where all of the >0.05 values overlap with the 0's. This means that no 1's get flipped. This will almost always happen if `letterA` is sparse. Only in a few rare cases your random matrix produces a pattern that flips ~5% of the 1's. Also, you're counting the total number of nonzero elements, not how many 1's have been flipped out of the total number of 1's, so your test-code is invalid.

Comment: Well N1 - nnz(letterA) is the number of flipped ones and (N1 - nnz(letterA))/N1 is the percentage of flipped ones, which should be around 5%. Correct me if I am wrong.
But I agree, that my code flipps a one to a zero with 5% probability, which does not mean that exactly 5 % of ones are flipped (only if there is a large number of ones).

Comment: You know what, I admit I didn't give it the proper thought. But while it flips 5% on average, the deviation might very well be unacceptable. So one trial might give you 3%, and one might give you 7%, producing 5% on average... is this what the OP wants?

Comment: Hi Eitan, I agree with you. it depends on the OP application. If he wants to simulate real noise, than it should be uncorrelated to the signal and then it is only 5% on average (so it could be 3% or 7%). But since we dont know what he wants, it is unclear. Also as Rody mentioned, true noise should also flip zeros to ones ....

Comment: "Noise" is a broad concept. It may be correlated or uncorrelated... I infer from the question that "flipping 5% of the ones" means correlated noise, because you're not flipping any zeroes. Anyway, I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

The basic approach is to find the indices of the 1's and count them, randomly pick a desired amount of indices out of them, and then operate on them:

```
one_flip_ratio = 0.05;
idx_ones = find(letterA == 1);                          %// Indices of 1's
flips = round(one_flip_ratio * numel(idx_ones));        %// Number of flips
idx_flips = idx_ones(randperm(numel(idx_ones), flips)); %// Indices of elements
letterA(idx_flips) = 0;                                 %// Flip elements
```

This will flip 5% of the 1's to 0's.

Comment: +1, however, the OP did say *"around"* 5%, whereas you are doing *exactly* 5%. This makes Andreas' solution a lot more appealing...

Comment: Hmm, this does not work for me:
letterA = (rand(1e5,1) < 0.1);
N1 = nnz(letterA); Your code ...  ; (N1 - nnz(letterA))/N1  gives for me 0.5% and not 5%.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for throwing out all these ideas, but eventually I came up with this. It will allow me to easily control both letter and background noise, which is what I intend to do. I'm just a novice, so this may not be the most efficient code, but it gets the job done! (I'm not looking for exactly 5%, the naked eye display value is what I'm more worried about.) PLEASE let me know how this can be improved! Thank you.

```
background_noise_intensity=0.05;
letter_noise_intensity=0.05;

for i=1:numel(letterA)
    if letterA(i)==0
        if rand < background_noise_intensity
            letterA(i)=1;
        end
    elseif letterA(i)==1
        if rand < letter_noise_intensity
            letterA(i)=0;
        end
    end
end

noisy_letters=letterA;

reshaped_noisy_letters=reshape(noisy_letters,37,19)';
imshow(reshaped_noisy_letters);
```

Comment: Looks ok, I cant provide any fundamental suggestions here. Just if you want it to be more efficient you could write
letterA_orig = letterA;
letterA( letterA == 1 & rand(size(letterA)) < letter_noise_intensity ) = 0; 
letterA( letterA_orig == 0 & rand(size(letterA)) < background_noise_intensity ) = 1;
Note that this works for letterA of arbitrary dimensionality. So the reshape could also be before, or, the reshape is not necessary, if letterA already is a 37x19 matrix.

Comment: @ShankarKumar Is it really this type of noise you're looking for? Why not simply flip bits randomly? _e.g_: `idx = rand(size(letterA)) < tol; letterA (idx) = ~letterA(idx);`. You can control the noise intensity with the threshold `tol`.